# Selecting default Boolean value in <form:select> in SpringMVC

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc

I have a problem with from in Spring MVC. Selecting something in form and submitting the form works perfectly, selecting default value for non-Boolean values also works, but I have problem selecting default value for Booleans.

My jsp file looks something like this:

```
<form:form commandName="filterData" id="user_filter_form" action="${listUrl}" method="POST">
    <form:label path="active">Active</form:label><br/>
    <form:select path="active">
        <option value="">--</option>
        <option value="true">Yes</option>
        <option value="false">No</option>
    </form:select>

    <form:label path="email">E-mail</form:label><br/>
    <form:input path="email" type="search"/>

    <button class="b not-ui" type="submit" style="margin-right: 25px">Search</button>
</form:form>
```

Model object is like this:

```
public class UserFilterData {
    private Boolean active;
    private String email;

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public Boolean getActive() {
        return active;
    }

    public void setActive(Boolean active) {
        this.active = active;
    }
}
```

As I said, submitting works fine, but when I create controller like this, "email" field is filled with "test@example.com", but selectbox has selected the first option "---"

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/filter")
public String filterAction(Model model) {
    UserFilterData data = new UserFilterData();
    data.setEmail("test@example.com");
    data.setActive(Boolean.TRUE);
    model.addAttribute("filterData", data);
    return "users/index;
}
```

I also tried change "true" in my jsp to ${true} or TRUE or 1, but without any success. If I echo filterData in jsp using `${filterData.active}`, the result is `true`, but appropriate option is not selected. Does anyone have an idea what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably need to use the form options tag.

```
<form:option value="true" label=""/>
<form:option value="false" label=""/>
```

Comment: I must have been blind, I've been looking on it with my colleague and we both didn't notice. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You are not using the Spring tags appropriately.

One simple way you could change your code would be:

```
<form:select path="active">
     <form:option value="">--</option>
     <form:options items="${activeValues}" itemLabel="active" itelLabel="active" >
</form:select>


@RequestMapping(value = "/filter")
public String filterAction(Model model) {
    UserFilterData data = new UserFilterData();
    data.setEmail("test@example.com");
    data.setActive(Boolean.TRUE);
    model.addAttribute("filterData", data);
    model.addAttribute("activeValues", Lists.newArrayList("yes", "no"));
    return "users/index;
}
```

The way you are using the tags, Spring won't know when to add the `selected` value to the rendered HTML `option`